# ToolBartray.Orientation = vertical and width of toolbar

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, toolbar

I have a Problem with the width of the toolbars in my toolbartray if I set orientation to vertical.
The width has the minimum size of the Overflow item.

I want that the toolbar width has the size of the first Button.

```
<ToolBarTray Orientation="Vertical" DockPanel.Dock="Left" >
  <ToolBar>
     <Button Content="ii" />
     <Button Content="iizzuzzuzuz" ToolBar.OverflowMode="Always"/>
   </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

How can I do that? Has someone the same Problem?

Kind regards,
Kevin